# Invoke wrong Asset URL in single spa micro front-end

Tags: angular, single-spa-angular

I am using single-spa library to achieve micro front-end functionality.

I am using assets to display in the pages. But the URL that is generated to fetch assets is wrong.

For instance, I have used information.svg icon in self-service application then the URL is expected to be 'https://customer.tcm.com/self-service/assets/information.svg'. But the URL that is being fetched is 'https://customer.tcm.com/root/assets/information.svg' or 'https://customer.tcm.com/assets/information.svg' which obviously returns 404 response.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier? Can someone help me here to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience

anguler ex -> `index.html`

`base href="."` OR `base href="/"`
change to
`base href="/server_root/"`

Comment: For more info about `base-href` see https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href.